# Updating tables without naming all columns

Tags: sql-server-2005, insert-update, multiple-columns

I have found a way to make two tables from different databases match each other using this template:

```
INSERT [DestDB].[dbo].[TABLE]
SELECT source.* FROM 
[SourceDB].[dbo].[TABLE] AS source
LEFT OUTER JOIN
[DestDB].[dbo].[TABLE] AS dest
ON 
source.[PKColumn] = dest.[PKColumn]
WHERE dest.[PKcolumn] IS NULL

UPDATE dest
SET 
 dest.[PK_COLUMN1] = source.[PK_COLUMN1]
,dest.[COLUMN2] = source.[COLUMN2]
,dest.[COLUMN3] = source.[COLUMN3]
,dest.[COLUMN4] = source.[COLUMN4]
,dest.[COLUMN5] = source.[COLUMN5]
,dest.[COLUMN6] = source.[COLUMN6]
,dest.[COLUMN7] = source.[COLUMN7]
,dest.[COLUMN8] = source.[COLUMN8]

FROM 
[SourceDB].[dbo].[TABLE] AS source
INNER JOIN 
[DestDB].[dbo].[TABLE] AS dest
ON source.[PK_Column1] = dest.[PK_Column1]
```

However some tables I am working with have at least 200 columns and while it is possible to do this through the power of Copy + Paste, I just need to know if there is a way that doesn't involve me getting Carpel Tunnel Syndrome.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Any advice?

Comment: Do all columns from the two tables (dest and source) match?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can update columns without naming them, but you can use SQL and the sys.columns view to script it for you:

```
select ',dest.[' + name + '] = source.[' + name +']' 
from sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Widgets]')
```

-- output --

```
,dest.[WidgetId] = source.[WidgetId]
,dest.[WidgetName] = source.[WidgetName]
,dest.[CreatedDt] = source.[CreatedDt]
,dest.[WidgetValue] = source.[WidgetValue]
,dest.[ModifiedDt] = source.[ModifiedDt]
```

The only other way is to NOT update, but instead truncate the dest table and perform a `SELECT INTO`

```
SELECT * INTO DEST FROM SOURCE
```

Comment: First of all: lifesaver. Secondly, this code will NOT work, because while updating, you are not allowed to give an Alias to the table being updated. For example,  UPDATE [DestTable] dest
 SET    
  dest.RecordType = source.RecordType FROM   SourceTable source .. WILL NOT work

Comment: how you could make it work is through removing ALIAS: UPDATE DestTable SET RecordType = Source.RecordType FROM sourceTable source

Comment: Yes, aliases can be used in update statements. But the code will work just as good without one too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql (and the info @ChrisGessler provided) to do what you want.

Another possibility, if you can't or don't want to use it, is:

1. Pass the rows that match into a new table
2. delete the rows in the dest table
3. add the rows in the dest table

---

Step 1 may be something like this:

```
SELECT * INTO newtable
FROM 
[SourceDB].[dbo].[TABLE] AS source
INNER JOIN 
[DestDB].[dbo].[TABLE] AS dest
ON source.[PK_Column1] = dest.[PK_Column1]
```

Remember to drop the newtable in the end.

Comment: This won't work, if you have FK in the dest table because of referential integrity. If that's not the case, why bother to copy rows from one table to another, instead of just delete and full reinsert into dest table?

Comment: @oerl this also really answers another scenario in which you are deleting rows in the dest table.. which , i find, to be rarity in updates.